# Cake PHP 3 : Find Query for belongsToMany - get Entity related in join table

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, join

I have three tables in cake php 3 :
- ImagesTable
- ImagesHasImagesTable
- ImageTypesTable

One Image has many ChildImages. That I have linked together with a 
belongsToMany Association.

```
$this->belongsToMany('ChildImages',[
        'className' => 'Images',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'images_id',
        'foreignKey' => 'original_id',
        'joinTable' => 'images_has_images',
]);
```

Now I get the (almost) desired result with a "child_images" array containing all related images
This is the query :

```
$image = $imageTable->get($id,['contain' => ['ChildImages']]);
```

and this the specific part in the result :

```
[child_images] => Array(
     [0] => Array(
        [id] => 36
        [image_size] => 269442
        [image_width] => 726
        ....
        [_joinData] => Array(
            [original_id] => 13
            [images_id] => 36
            [image_types_id] => 1
        )
     )
)
```

What I need is the related Entity from ImageTypes with [image_types_id] => 1 inside the child image array. Is there any possibility to reach that without iterate through the array and doing one query for every single child_image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not (yet) possible to contain associations for join tables, not even when using the `through` option to provide a concrete table class (you may want to [**suggest that as an enhancement**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues)).

What you can do is create an extra association for the join table, and use a concrete table class that provides an association for `ImageTypes` too, something like:

```
class ImagesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        // ...

        $this->hasMany('ImagesHasImages',[
            'foreignKey' => 'original_id'
        ]);
    }
}
```

and for the `ImagesHasImagesTable` class:

```
class ImagesHasImagesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        // ...

        $this->belongsTo('Images', [
            'alias' => 'Images',
            'foreignKey' => 'original_id'
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('ChildImages', [
            'alias' => 'Tags',
            'foreignKey' => 'image_id'
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('ImageTypes');
    }
}
```

With the extra association for `ImageTypes` you can contain the data like:

```
['ImagesHasImages' => ['ChildImages', 'ImageTypes']]
```

The returned structure of course will be a little different, so you may need to reformat it.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Togethe > Using the ‘through’ Option](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option)**

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using "**[junction()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Association.BelongsToMany.html#_junction)**"

```
$imageTable->ChildImages->junction();

$image = $imageTable->get($id,

    ['contain' => 
      ['ImagesHasImagesTable',
       'ImagesHasImagesTable.ImageTypes', 
       'ImagesHasImagesTable.ChildImages'
      ]

]);
```